# How to optimize other metrics in fold out method efficiently?

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, classification, evaluation

What is the efficient way to alter an optimization target function in scikit-learn classifier?

I want to use f1-score in training classifier. Looking at codes, a simple way is to override score function which is implemented in ClassifierMixin. Usually, I accept this.

However, this needs to write more code when I use a lot of classifiers because classifier cannot be modified by arguments.

I guess,

1. Externalize scorer function
2. Override ClassifierMixin in my codes after import
3. Give up and override scores for each

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `GridSearch` takes a `scorer` parameter

Comment: Are you sure you don't confuse the notions of the *loss* (which is the quantity we actually optimize in classification settings) with that of *score* or *metric* (such as accuracy, f1 score etc), which has nothing to do with the optimization part?

Comment: I understand the difference btw loss and metrics. In my case, I want to maxmize f1-score in traning model because the model is necessary to not only answer high accurately, but also balance the mistakes. Even if the model would got high accuracy and low recall (or low precision), we cannot accept model.